# PHP. Can't get body of POST request

Tags: php, post, postman

I am trying to get body of POST Request. I send it using POSTMAN. But the body of POST request is always empty. I tried to swap between http and https, but it's useless for me. PHP get the POST request, but it's always empty.

I'm using php 5.3 and OpenServer for my project.

Here is my request

```
POST /example HTTP/1.1
Host: domain
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.17.1
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://ht-line/integration/proctoring/proctorEdu
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache


{

  "something":94

}
```

Here is php code

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

$data = json_decode($json);
```

var_dump($json);

```
string '' (length=0)
```

**UPDATE**

If I do request in domain folder like http://domain it works fine, but if I change it to http://domain/test it doesn't work

Comment: You're missing the `Content-length:` header.

Comment: What does `var_dump($json)` output?